# Oracle SQL Select - Valid select list according to syntax diagram

Tags: sql, oracle, select, syntax

I ran a SELECT-Statement like the following in Oracle successfully:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM table_a a, table_b b;
```

Here I give table table_a the alias 'a' and table_b the alias 'b'.
Then I use the two table aliases in the select list ('a.*, b.*')
with an asterisk for each table alias to select all columns from both
tables.

Sure, I could just use '*' as select list to get all columns
from both tables, but it's about what is valid for the select list
(like here 'a.*, b.*').

I can execute a statement like the one above, but when I look at the syntax diagram for the select list in Oracle's documentation, it seems as it would be not valid to use multiple table aliases in the select list.

The question is, whether it is possible to derive something like ('a.*, b.*') with the syntax diagram for the select list. In the syntax diagram it seems, as if I can just have one table alias in the select, because I can't 'travel back' in the diagram to add a comma and an other table alias.

Syntax diagram: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/img/select_list.gif

General description for SELECT:  http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702

Comment: As an aside, try to avoid the [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @JohnHC Usually I use new style joins, thank you. Here I'm just curious about valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. If you have more values then you just need to traverse back to comma as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Seems like a small oversight/bug in the diagram where this confusion would be clarified by swapping the `comma` path to be on the outside and the `[t_alias].*` inside it.

Comment: I think they tried to use single comma for other expressions in the syntax diagram. For example, the same comma is being used for other expression such as `schema.table.*` and `expr as c_alias`.

Comment: However, the syntax `SELECT *, 1 FROM DUAL` is invalid but `SELECT d.*, 1 FROM DUAL d` is valid - so swapping the position of those two paths in the syntax diagram would work for the second example but would also imply that the first should be valid syntax (which it isn't).

Comment: @MT0 Good point - if traveling from the alias path back over the comma path, SELECT *, 1 FROM DUAL would be valid.